# Different behavior of bpy.ops.transform.resize in Edit mode

Tags: scripting, transforms

If I set Transform Pivot Point to individual origins & scale faces - We get something like this.

[image]

and console logs my scaling operation was this following call:

```
bpy.ops.transform.resize(
    value=(1.97597, 1.97597, 1.97597),
    orient_type='GLOBAL',
    orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)),
    orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL',
    mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False,
    proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH',
    proportional_size=1,
    use_proportional_connected=False,
    use_proportional_projected=False,
    snap=False,
    snap_elements={'INCREMENT'},
    use_snap_project=False,
    snap_target='CLOSEST',
    use_snap_self=True,
    use_snap_edit=True,
    use_snap_nonedit=True,
    use_snap_selectable=False
)
```

But if I copy this call and paste in console, I get something very different:

[image]

Which seems to be scaled using object origin as pivot. Even logged command contains `constraint_axis(True, True, True)` which isn't what I supplied. (Except different scale value)

```
bpy.ops.transform.resize(
    value=(4.89765, 4.89765, 4.89765),
    orient_type='GLOBAL',
    orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)),
    orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL',
    constraint_axis=(True, True, True),
    mirror=True,
    use_proportional_edit=False,
    proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH',
    proportional_size=1,
    use_proportional_connected=False,
    use_proportional_projected=False,
    snap=False,
    snap_elements={'INCREMENT'},
    use_snap_project=False,
    snap_target='CLOSEST',
    use_snap_self=True,
    use_snap_edit=True,
    use_snap_nonedit=True,
    use_snap_selectable=False
)
```

Does scripting API not support Transform Pivot Point other than object origin?
I need my script to be able to scale via individual origins in Edit mode.

Searched about 2 hours now and no luck, other than 8-yr-old answers, sadly